# Infinite tension in conical pendulum?

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

Consider a conical pendulum. Let $\alpha$ be the acute angle between the string and the vertical, $T$ be the magnitude of the tension in the string and $mg$ be the magnitude of the gravitational force acting on the pendulum vertically downwards.

Then, according to my 1st year Mathematics BSc Vectors and Mechanics course,
\begin{align}
T\cos\alpha=mg,\tag{1}
\end{align}

so 
\begin{align}
T=\frac{mg}{\cos\alpha}.\tag{2}
\end{align}

From this, it seems to me, it follows that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}T&=\lim_{\cos\alpha\rightarrow 0}T\tag{3.1}\\
&=\frac{mg}{0}\tag{3.2}\\
&=\infty\tag{3.3},
\end{align}

but this is unphysical, since the string of a horizontally spinning pendulum does not have infinite tension.

What have I missed?

Comment: This is physical.  No pendulum on earth will ever spin completely horizontal--it will always sag a bit under gravity.  In order to spin truly horizontal, it would have to spin infinitely fast, and would then require infinite string tension.

Comment: @Yly OK. If you care to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Also a realistic string has a finite endurance.  It will have a maximum spinning angle above which the string will tear apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is physical. No pendulum on earth will ever spin completely horizontal--it will always sag a bit under gravity. In order to spin truly horizontal, it would have to spin infinitely fast, and would then require infinite string tension.